# Graphic Recognition of People

Tags: image-recognition

I would like to know what is the best approach to begin a project to perform graphical recognition of people.  In other words, the computer will parse an image file and through a heuristic figure out if it sees the shape of a person.

Any API's or open sources available, is this too ahead of the times?

Thanks

Comment: The most obvious thing which comes to mind is OpenCV, there is an introduction to face detection here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you searching for face detection or people detection?

If face-detection:

OpenCV comes with samples for face detection. And OpenCV 2.4-beta has samples for face recognition also. Check here : http://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp
If people-detection:

OpenCV comes with a sample for people-detection using [HOG descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients). [Link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp)

This is the result i obtained with above code:

[image]

Comment: I want to detect human in an image, but in matlab as I am new to matlab I have no idea about OpenCV as well so it would be hard for me to bridge between them do I have any other option ?