# Code for Human Detection using OpenCV GPU

Tags: opencv, gpu, video-processing, face-detection, object-detection

Currecntly i am working on Real time Human/People/fact detection in Video using OpenCV and GPU. i am in need of the OpenCv code for the video processing and human detection in video. Please help me to find code for human dectection in video using Opencv or any other programming. Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Comment: This question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. See [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/163653).

Answer (score 6):

I have already discussed some options to do this in another SOF question : [Graphic Recognition of People](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231380/graphic-recognition-of-people)

There, i have provided links for the codes of `Face detection using Haar cascades` and `People detection using HOG descriptors` which already comes with OpenCV Samples. You can use them.

For example, below is the result of people detection i obtained with that code:

[image]

But people detection can be a little bit slow. But for your luck, OpenCV comes with some `GPU optimized functions` in which HOG descriptor functions and cascade classifier  functions also included. So you can implement above two samples in GPU.

Check here for complete documentation : [Object Detection GPU](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#object-detection)