# Human detection from the image or video library

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I want to recognize the human from the image or video. I have used OPENCVSharp for Face detection it works fine with front face and low accuracy for side face. what i want is human detection (face detection wont work b'z face might be opposite to camera).

Can any one suggest any library or reference link for human detection from either image or video ? Also is it possible to identify the gender out of it ? is there any way we can track human from the video ?

Comment: Try the [Cascade Classifier](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/apps/traincascade/cascadeclassifier.cpp?rev=2335) with [haarcascade_fullbody.xml](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades). [Example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html).

Comment: Did you retrain classifier for side face?

Comment: Google: hog video human detection

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231380/graphic-recognition-of-people/10385464#10385464

Comment: This question is a bad candidate for this site. This question is a shopping list question, more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic
 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: Thanks Abid for sharing the link, will go through the link and if i have any doubts will ask you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to investigate either Haar or HoG detection and decide which best suits your problem. You will then need to follow the same steps that you have conducted for face recognition but with a dataset that includes people instead.

Use this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) which has a long list of free to use (non commercial) datasets which you can find one to use

then use [opencv_traincascades](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) to get your cascade.xml file